# Event while cancelling a appointment in outlook

Tags: .net

I am working in Outlook addins 2010, I need to do a database hit while cancelling an appointment in the outlook, I already gone through previuos postings, not able to find anything.
I excatly want to know which event will be called while cancelling an appointment?

Comment: Could you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: please find below my code

Comment: Outlook.MAPIFolder calendar = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            Outlook.Items calendarItems = calendar.Items;

            if (calendar != null)
            {
                if (calendarItems != null)
                {
                    calendarItems.ItemRemove += calendarItems_ItemRemove;
                }
            }, i tried delete event also, BeforeDelete event, where this will hit on deleting a meeting invite, I need the event while clicking the 'Send Cancellation' button